# How do I access the Node Access User Reference configuration?

Tags: 7, users

I've installed the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) and [Node Access User Reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) modules on my Drupal 7 system.  I've added a User Reference field to a content type, and can happily add user references to nodes.

However, on the Node Access User Reference's project page, it shows a screenshot of a configuration form which I cannot find.  I want to grant referenced users editing rights, but cannot find where to do this.  Where do I find this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a clue in the README.txt which I'd previously missed

> Create a field to reference users in a content type using the Field UI.  The field's
>   configuration page will contain the settings for Node access user reference.

I edited the User Reference field I'd created, and on the Edit tab was a collapsed heading for *Node access user reference* that I'd previously missed.  Clicking the heading revealed the configuration form.